# Kubernetes Nginx Ingress partial ssl termination

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'd like to split incoming traffic in Kubernetes Nginx in the following way:

```
Client --> Nginx --> {Service A, Service B}
```

The problem I am facing is Service A is an internal service and does not support HTTPS therefore SSL should be terminated for Service A. On the other hand, Service B is an external service (hosted on example.com) and only works over HTTPS.

I cannot manage to get this work easily with Kubernetes Nginx. Here is what I have come with:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-proxy
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/upstream-vhost: example.com
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - proxy.com
    secretName: secret
  rules:
    - host: proxy.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/v1/endpoint
            backend:
              serviceName: service-a
              servicePort: 8080
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: service-b
              servicePort: 443
```

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
name: service-b
namespace: default
spec:
type: ExternalName
externalName: service-b.external
ports:
- port: 443

I have got a route for `service-b.external:443` to point to example.com.

This solution only works if service-b is over HTTPS, but in my case, I cannot change to HTTPS for this service because of some other internal dependencies.

My problem is the `backend-protocol` annotation works for the whole kind and I cannot define it per path.

P.S: I am using AWS provider

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's entirely possible, and reasonable, to have two `Ingress` resources, one annotated with `backend-protocol:` and the other not; the Ingress controller merges all Ingress resources across the entire cluster and most-specific wins (so `/api/v1/endpoint` will be routed to service-a and if its Ingress resource isn't annotated, it will use HTTP by default)

Comment: @mdaniel How does it work with a single host: proxy.com? Both will be pointing to the same address. Does ingress support two items with the same host?

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggested solution and question from comments.

Yes, like mentioned below it is possible to have two ingress items. In your case
only one should have backend-protocol in it.

According to nginx ingress documentation:

> ## Basic usage - host based routing[¶](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/#basic-usage-host-based-routing)
>
> ingress-nginx can be used for many use cases, inside various cloud provider and supports a lot of configurations. In this section you can find a common usage scenario where a single load balancer powered by ingress-nginx will route traffic to 2 different HTTP backend services based on the host name.
>
> First of all follow the instructions to install ingress-nginx. Then imagine that you need to expose 2 HTTP services already installed:  `myServiceA`,  `myServiceB`. Let's say that you want to expose the first at  `myServiceA.foo.org`  and the second at  `myServiceB.foo.org`. One possible solution is to create two  **ingress**  resources:
>
> ```
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: ingress-myservicea
>   annotations:
>     # use the shared ingress-nginx
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
> spec:
>   rules:
>   - host: myservicea.foo.org
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - path: /
>         backend:
>           serviceName: myservicea
>           servicePort: 80
> ---
> apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: Ingress
> metadata:
>   name: ingress-myserviceb
>   annotations:
>     # use the shared ingress-nginx
>     kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
> spec:
>   rules:
>   - host: myserviceb.foo.org
>     http:
>       paths:
>       - path: /
>         backend:
>           serviceName: myserviceb
>           servicePort: 80
> ```
>
> When you apply this yaml, 2 ingress resources will be created managed by the  **ingress-nginx**  instance. Nginx is configured to automatically discover all ingress with the  `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"`  annotation. Please note that the ingress resource should be placed inside the same namespace of the backend resource.
>
> On many cloud providers ingress-nginx will also create the corresponding Load Balancer resource. All you have to do is get the external IP and add a DNS  `A record`  inside your DNS provider that point myServiceA.foo.org and myServiceB.foo.org to the nginx external IP. Get the external IP by running:
>
> `kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx`

It is also possible to have separate nginx classes as mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/multiple-ingress/#multiple-ingress-nginx-controllers).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I think you have misunderstood my question. In fact, I need both service-a and service-b to have the same host as proxy.com in my example. The problem is as soon as I use the same host it doesn't work as expected.